# What are good references for .Net development with Office Communications Server?

Tags: .net, asp.net, silverlight, communication, voip

Is is possible to intergrate VOIP capabilities, particularly phone dialing, with Office Communications Server 2007 and .Net? If so, are there any good references for this? I would be especially interested if this could be hosted within an ASP.Net or Silverlight application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Thirsty Developer](http://www.thirstydeveloper.com) did a [podcast](http://thirstydeveloper.com/2008/09/22/TheThirstyDeveloper36WPFGadgetsAndUC.aspx) recently on a Vista Gadget hooked into MOC recently. IIRC, they used either Silverlight or a WPF XBAP to host the Gadget.

The [project](http://www.codeplex.com/MOCVistaGadget) is open sourced on Codeplex, and MS also released some [presence controls](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=5001d612-533a-4721-91ea-da990d94ff0f&DisplayLang=en) for WPF that went with it.

Edit: There seem to be diffent APIs depending on where you want to hook into (do you want to use the client Communicator, or integrate direct to your app, etc.). Here's a couple of pointers to the resources I know about:

- http://blogs.msdn.com/jcalev/archive/2007/08/21/an-overview-of-the-apis-in-office-communications-server-2007.aspx
- Download [Microsoft Unified Communications Managed API SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=B30306E4-7DC1-44D2-9A68-9B4A6FC5C2DF&displaylang=en), and [docs online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb759538.aspx)
- [Unified Communications Client API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb878516.aspx)
- [Office Communicator SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=ed1cce45-cc22-46e1-bd50-660fe6d2c98c&DisplayLang=en)

Comment: I had listened to that podcast recently and was already pondering that, and appreciate you reminding me.

Comment: I was also curious if other resources existed besides that too.